# AndroidHttpClient is deprecated

Tags: java, android, http, httpconnection, androidhttpclient

Well, my ImageDownloader class is broken with the new Sdk. How would I go about making this work now? Any possibility I could just replace some of the following classes without making major changes to my code?

```
static Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
        final AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
        final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
            final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode + " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
                return null;
            }

            final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    return bitmap;
                } finally {
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        inputStream.close();
                    }
                    entity.consumeContent();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Could provide a more explicit error message for IOException or IllegalStateException
            getRequest.abort();
            Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
        } finally {
            if (client != null) {
                client.close();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Exactly what is broken and what errors are you now receiving?

Comment: Why did you ever use the `AndroidHttpClient`? It is literally ancient, it hasn't been recommended for years. Only in the very earliest of Android versions. You should have replaced this a long time ago. Anyway, why the big fuss? It's just one method. Rewriting it should be quite simple. What did you try so far? Why couldn't you do it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
```

or this in the gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' //<-this line only
```

or you can just update the code and use the `HttpURLConnection` like this:

```
URL url = new URL("your_url");
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
setupDataToDB();
OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
bufferedWriter.write(StringGenerator.queryResults(nameValuePairs));
bufferedWriter.flush();
bufferedWriter.close();
outputStream.close();
httpURLConnection.connect();
InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
```

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can take an inputStream from:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
try {
    URL url = new URL(path);
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTON_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(CONNECTON_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
    inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    //add code to take bitmap here
} finally {
    if (urlConnection != null) {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

and than take bitmap from it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also explore [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) htttp client